# Inequality in $\mathbb{C}$ using continuous functions

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

Let $f:[a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a continuous and differentiable function (which means that both $Re(f)$ and $Im(f)$ are differentiable and $f' = Re(f)' + iIm(f)'$). We are to proof that:
$$|f(b) - f(a)| \le |b-a|\sup_{t \in [a,b]}|f'(t)|$$
I tried to solve that problem using Lagrange theorem but unfortunately I failed. I would appreciate any tips or hints.

Comment: Hint: think about this first with $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Can you prove that at some point $x_0$ on the interval, it must be that $|f'(x_0)| \geq \left | \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b-a} \right |$  ? Can you see what to do from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exists a complex number $\alpha$ with $|\alpha|=1$ such that $\alpha(f(b)-f(a))\ge0$. Define $g(t)=\Re(\alpha f(t))$ and apply the Mean Value Theorem to $g$; then use the fact that $|g'|\le|f'|$.

Comment: Why do we know that such $\alpha$ exists?

Comment: Write $f(b)-f(a)$ in polar form $re^{it}$...

Comment: Thanks! Now I think I understand that part. Another question - when can we use $|g'| \le |f'|$? After using MVT I've got something like this: $\frac{Re \alpha(f(b)-f(a))}{b-a} = g'(c)$ Where can I use the argument that $|g'| \le |f'|$? Because $g \le f$?

Comment: If $z=x+iy$ is a complex number then $|x|\le|z|$. So $|g'|\le|\alpha f'|=|f'|$.

Comment: Thank you! Now everything is clear to me! :)